# Preserving order of prerequisites in $^ in GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Given this makefile

```
.SUFFIXES: .mmd .tmp .html

a.html : h.tmp a.tmp
b.html : h.tmp b.tmp
c.html : h.tmp c.tmp C.tmp

.tmp.html:
        cat $^ > $@

.mmd.tmp:
        Markdown.pl $< > $@
```

where `h.mmd` is a header to be inserted at the start of each html file.

The command `make ?.html` produces this

```
$ touch h.mmd
$ make ?.html
Markdown.pl h.mmd > h.tmp
cat a.tmp h.tmp > a.html
cat b.tmp h.tmp > b.html
cat c.tmp h.tmp C.tmp > c.html
```

The prerequisites have been sorted alphabetically. Can I preserve the order specified in the dependency lines so that the `cat` command includes each part in the specified order?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have anything to do with alphabetical order or sorting.  The prerequisites are not sorted and the value of $^ is not rearranged, with one exception:

In all implicit rules the implicit dependency is always the first element in the prerequisite list, regardless of whether you added it later as an explicit prerequisite in a different location.

It might be simpler to see if you convert your suffix rule into a pattern rule (but both work the same):  A suffix rule like:

```
.tmp.html: ; cmd
```

is the same thing as a pattern rule like:

```
%.html: %.tmp ; cmd
```

So if you have:

```
%.html: %.tmp ; @echo $^

c.html : d.tmp b.tmp c.tmp a.tmp
```

because the pattern match for a target `c.html` is `c`, the matching prerequisite `c.tmp` will always be the first prerequisite even though they're listed in different order in the explicit prerequisites list.  So the output of this will be:

```
c.tmp d.tmp b.dmp a.tmp
```

Note: not sorted, but the matching prerequisite appears first.

There is no way to "turn this off".  The only solution, as suggested by @RedGrittyBrick, is to not list the prerequisite pattern at all.  You can use their idea of:

```
%.html: ; @echo $^

c.html : d.tmp b.tmp c.tmp a.tmp
```

Or continue to use a suffix rule like:

```
.html: ; @echo $^

c.html : d.tmp b.tmp c.tmp a.tmp
```

and both will give the same result:

```
d.tmp b.tmp c.tmp a.tmp
```

Comment: Is the behavior "the matching prerequisite in a pattern rule will always appear as the first prerequisite in the list (and thus in the expansion of $^)" documented anywhere in the GNU Make docs?
Also, can I assume that the order of the prerequisites will be the same as I specify them, if I only have explicit prerequisites lists, in multiple rules?
As in
`
target : prereq1
target: prereq2 prereq3
target:
    echo $^
`

Comment: Sorry the comment screwed up my formatting, and I cannot edit anymore. I meant:

`target: prereq1 <newline> target: prereq2 prereq3 <newline> target: <newline><tab>echo $^`

Comment: Yes, it's documented in the GNU Make manual and also in the POSIX spec (with respect to suffix rules; pattern rules are not part of POSIX).

Answer (score 0):

I don't properly understand this but one way that worked for me was to make a one-line change to replace the suffix rule `.tmp.html:` with a pattern rule `%.html:`

```
.SUFFIXES: .mmd .tmp .html

a.html : h.tmp a.tmp
b.html : h.tmp b.tmp
c.html : h.tmp c.tmp C.tmp

%.html:
        cat $^ > $@

.mmd.tmp:
        Markdown.pl $< > $@
```

which preserves order

```
$ touch h.mmd
$ make ?.html
Markdown.pl h.mmd > h.tmp
cat h.tmp a.tmp > a.html
cat h.tmp b.tmp > b.html
cat h.tmp c.tmp C.tmp > c.html
```

So that is an answer, albeit incomplete because ...

What I understand:

- A target can have multiple rules.
- $^ is the combined set of all prerequisites from all rules for a target.

What I don't understand:

- Why this affects the order of the elements of $^ in the same command.